# SQL Server Copy Random data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, random, copy, newid

I have 2 tables `stuff` and `nonsense`. `nonsense` is not the same size as `stuff`; in this case it is has fewer rows, but it may have more.

The structures are something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    details VARCHAR(MAX),
    data VARCHAR(MAX)
);

CREATE TABLE nonsense (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR(MAX)
);
```

The `stuff` table is already populated with `details`, but `data` is `NULL` for now.

I would like to copy data from *one* row of `nonsense` *at random* into each row of `stuff`. Since `nonsense` is smaller, there will naturally be duplicates, which is OK.

This does *not* work:

```
UPDATE stuff
SET data=(SELECT TOP 1 data FROM nonsense ORDER BY NewId());
```

Presumably the sub query is evaluated once before the rest of the query. However that’s the sort of result I would have liked.

How do I achive this?

Comment: *This does not work,* you mean same value is updated for all the records in data column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correlate the sub-query to run it for each record.

```
UPDATE stuff
SET data=(SELECT TOP 1 data 
          FROM nonsense 
          where stuff.id = stuff.id  --here
          ORDER BY NewId());
```

Comment: @Manngo - that where clause makes the sub-query to execute for each row