# PostGresql: Copy data from a random row of another table

Tags: postgresql, join, random, copy, lateral

I have two tables, `stuff` and `nonsense`.

```
create table stuff(
    id serial primary key,
    details varchar,
    data varchar,
    more varchar
);
create table nonsense (
    id serial primary key,
    data varchar,
    more varchar
);

insert into stuff(details) values
    ('one'),('two'),('three'),('four'),('five'),('six');
insert into nonsense(data,more) values
    ('apple','accordion'),('banana','banjo'),('cherry','cor anglais');
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/313fb/1

I would like to copy random values from `nonsense` to `stuff`. I can do this for a single value using the answer to my previous question: [SQL Server Copy Random data from one table to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385261/sql-server-copy-random-data-from-one-table-to-another):

```
update stuff
set data=(select data from nonsense where stuff.id=stuff.id
    order by random() limit 1);
```

However, I would like to copy more than one value (`data` and `more`) from the same row, and the sub query won’t let me do that, of course.

I Microsoft SQL, I can use the following:

```
update stuff
set data=sq.town,more=sq.state
from stuff s outer apply
    (select top 1 * from nonsense where s.id=s.id order by newid()) sq
```

I have read that PostGresql uses something like `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` instead of `OUTER APPPLY`, but simply substituting doesn’t work for me.

How can I update with multiple values from a random row of another table?

Answer (score 4):

As of Postgres 9.5, you can assign multiple columns from a subquery:

```
update stuff
set (data, more) = (
  select data, more
  from nonsense
  where stuff.id=stuff.id
  order by random()
  limit 1
);
```